# Working with duration display days without decreasing for more than 31

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007

I want column format to display duration as number of days as whole.
Ex:

```
ID | StartDate | EndDate    | Days (=C-B) | Days (formatted: d)  
1  | 2019-9-28 | 2019-10-23 |  25         | 25  
2  | 2019-9-23 | 2019-10-23 |  30         | 30  
3  | 2019-9-15 | 2019-10-23 |  38         | 7
```

**ID = 3** doesn't display 38 days as formatted. I want column format in MS Excel so that I can display 38 as whole.

Comment: How column `D` is formatted?

Comment: @TerryW I've fixed the data. I've tried to apply custom format in Excel as **d** *(also mentioned in column E)*

Comment: @Harun24HR Column D is formatted as  `Column C - Column B`

Comment: Do you mean you want Excel to "magically" change the result of `Col C - Col B` if it is over 31. For instance change `38` to `7` for ID3? If so you can try `=IF((Col C - Col B)>31,(Col C - Col B)-31,(Col C - Col B))`

Comment: `d` number format code returns the day **of the month**. Since there are a maximum of 31 days in a month, that is the range it will return.  What are you trying to accomplish with your format?  **ID 3** will display as 38 when formatted as `General` or as `Number with zero decimal places`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I want to accomplish is a column which displays "Days" when I place duration as value. This is the requirement for me because I'm using C# to populate column's value as TimeSpan and set column format *something* to display only "Days" out of Duration.

Comment: `EndDate- start date` **will** equal days. There's no need to format it as anything. If you **must** format it as something other than general, then format it as number with 0 decimal places

Comment: XL stores daytimes as days and fractions of the day since 1 January 1900. if you are getting decimal numbers from your subtraction then just apply the INT function to both start date and end date before subtracting them to eliminate any time component.

Comment: If what you want is to display the literal word "Days", then just a simple if formula `if(c2 > 0, "Days","")`

Comment: Try this : `=INT(C-B)` where C,B is the address of the compared dates. | Kindly share if it works/not.